# log4net Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file

Tags: logging, log4net

(Solution listed at the bottom of this post)

Working with Apache's log4net and having some interesting issues.

Here is my log4net.config, worth noting that I have multiple projects in the same solution, so this is placed in a shared project, with `Build Action` "Embedded resource" and `Copy to Output Directory` "Copy always" (And it is added to the output directory after building, for both projects in my solution)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="TextBoxAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="Logs\app.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date Thread: [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss.ffff} Thread: [%thread] %level %logger%exception - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="TextBoxAppender" type="app.TextBoxAppender, app">
      <targetFormName value="Form1" />
      <targetControlName value="tbLog" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss.ffff} Thread: [%thread] %level %logger%exception - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Here is my AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]
```

My understanding is that i can use `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()` to verify that the config is working correctly, when i do so i get this error

```
{log4net:ERROR XmlConfigurator: Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file. Check your .config file for the <log4net> and <configSections> elements. The configuration section should look like: <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />}
```

I thought the entire point of this

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
  </configSections>
```

was that i would not need to place it in my apps .config file?

Interestingly, if i run this `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));` it works without error and logs perfectly.
Is there a way i can change my config so i dont need to add the above line?

Edit 1:
Per pfx's comment, i corrected my `log4net.config` file content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="TextBoxAppender" />
  </root>
    
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs\AlphaTrade.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date Thread: [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss.ffff} Thread: [%thread] %level %logger%exception - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="TextBoxAppender" type="app.TextBoxAppender, app">
    <targetFormName value="Form1" />
    <targetControlName value="tbLog" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss.ffff} Thread: [%thread] %level %logger%exception - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

Still not working, also possibly worth noting `TextBoxAppender` is a custom appender.

Edit 2
Created a new console project and added the below config from `pfx` (but used file appender) and it all worked perfectly.

So, i went back to my real project and commented out everything but the `RollingFileAppender` in the config file.

My assembly directive is in the `assemblyinfo.cs` rather than in the class file, but that doesn't make a difference.

Still not working, in fact i noticed that it is not even creating the `Logs` folder. I deleted the `SharedProject` and moved the config file to the main project, still not working. I feel like i have some weird config issue, any thought on what i should be looking for?

Solution,
After doing some debugging and experimentation, i likely have some subtle config issue that i cant find. So, rather than chase it down here is what i did.

```
Remove the Assembly attribute.
Add this to the entry point method (main, [STAThread])
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
```

After that, everything works perfectly, is it right, IDK but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That call to `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()` results in an error because it instructs log4net to look for the `log4net` section in the main application configuration file, like `YourApp.exe.config` or `web.config`.

From the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_Config_XmlConfigurator_Configure.htm)

> Each application has a configuration file. This has the same name as the application with '`.config`' appended. This file is `XML` and calling this function prompts the configurator to look in that file for a section called `log4net` that contains the configuration data.

You have a custom file with name `log4net.config`.  That is why
`XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.config"))` succeeds.

---

About your `log4net.config` file.

The root xml tag should be `<log4net>` instead of `<configuration>`. That last one would only exist when using the main application configuration file.

The `<configSections>` declaration is only applicable when using the main application  configuration file, not when using a custom file.

Example of a custom file:

```
<log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <!- more configuration settings here --> 
    </root>  
    <!- more configuration settings here --> 
</log4net>
```

See the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html).

There's no need to set the `Build Action` of the `log4net.config` to `Embedded resource`, since you'll be copying it to the output folder anyway.

---

Do not combine both the `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]` attribute and a call to `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(...)`.

You choose one or the other.

In your case, just having the attribute defined in your main application suffices.

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]
```

---

A bare minimum example:

Program.cs:

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;

[assembly: XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("log");
        logger.Info("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Log4net.config:
Build Action: None, Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always

```
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  </root>
  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss.ffff} Thread: [%thread] %level %logger%exception - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

Comment: maybe i missed something, but its still not working, please see EDIT 1.

Comment: please see edit 2 (SO has too many pending edits right now, wont let me edit)

Comment: Sorry, wasn't expecting such a quick response from you, added edit 2 now ^

Comment: What info would be useful to know?

Comment: As a last try, put both the attribute and log4net.config (with copy to output dir) in only your main project - don't have them elsewhere. Use the log4net.config from my answer. And see what happens.

Comment: Thats exactly what i have right now, like i said in edit 2 i deleted the shared project.

Comment: In case this isn't a console app, then set the log4net.Appender.DebugAppender and watch the output window in Visual Studio, select the output from Debug

Comment: Its probably not right, but i will just create a module and use that as a startup object and have it run `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(...)` then launch the main form. and remove the assembly attribute.

Comment: I do think that is the better option; I've always use the `XmlConfigurator` when working with log4net; never had issues

Comment: This is NOT a console app, winforms, sorry neglected to mention that  (thought my custom appender would have hinted at it)

Comment: I'll do both, thanks again!